# Script interpreter

Tags: server-side-scripting

What script engine do you use/know for server side scripting besides:

- Delphi Web Script
- Php
- Python
- Ruby
- Morfik

I'm trying to create a list of less known scripting languages(preferable open source).

Comment: Why isn't Java listed?  Java has numerous scripting languages built on top of it, like JSP.

Comment: @S.Lott because I just enumerated a few, the idea is to make a list of less known scripting languages, I will update the question.

Comment: I voted to close cause the question in it's current form is to fuzzy. Why not list *all* options? Why exclude commercial options?

Comment: @Eugene because I'm NOT INTERESTED IN commercial!!

Comment: "(preferable open source)." and "NOT INTERESTED IN commercial!!" don't seem to be the same thing.  Can you clarify what you're looking for.  Can you do this without ALL CAPS and without !!'s?

Comment: OMG, can't believe this......... I prefer open source, but NOT the commercial ones -- obvious reasons -- you can also point to a "closed source" but it must be free to use for personal and commercial use without having to pay license.

Comment: Dude, you're just compiling a list, right? Nobody is going to make you use what's on your list. Why not make the list as good as it can be? Also voting to close.

Comment: @Chris Thornton WELL DUDE, just because you're a "all know" it doesn't mean that others(myself included) MUST know all scripting languages out there. Take Google for example, from what I know they use only open source, some people just don't have a clue about the expenses of a company... I don't get what's so bad about this question?! if you want to share super, if you don't, then just stay out of it, it's that simple. If you guys want to close this, it's fine by me, I vote to close also if that makes you feel better then what the hell?

Comment: why is it tagged as Delphi ? please remove the tag

Comment: @Dorin "I am not interested" doesn't correspond to "trying to create a list". If you are looking for one particular solution, state this and describe the goal so that others could address your need and not your curiosity. If you are trying to make a complete list, then do a complete list. Otherwise it doesn't make sense for anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget Lua, Groovy, Boo.

Answer (score 1):

[Perl](http://www.perl.org/) is quite popular and one of the oldest server side scripting languages. It's also well integrated with the [Apache web server](http://httpd.apache.org/) via [mod_perl](http://perl.apache.org/start/index.html).